# Does Java have a concept of reference ownership or noncopyable classes?

Tags: java

I would like to have some guarantee that instances of some particular class `Content` is only accessed by its "owner", and if another object wants the same `Content` it needs to take a deep copy. Coming from C++ I would achieve that using a `unique_ptr`, is there anything similar in Java?

Currently I am resolving this by just keeping the `Content` private everywhere I keep one and paying attention to creating a new `Content` (the constructor implements the deep copy mechanism) on a `getContent`. But I have no means of enforcing possible other users of the `Content` class to follow the same pattern, it's easy to forget. It would be nicer if it could take care of itself somehow, like not being copyable.

I realize that it goes somewhat against the spirit of the language, but in some cases I think it's justified. For example, if `Content` represents some stream of data that is modified even by reading it. I thought, if not in the core language, maybe there is some `@interface` for compile-time checking or a way of creating one?

**Edit:** The idea is that the owner *can* modify the object freely, before or after taking copies, and if someone takes a deep copy, they can modify theirs (not affecting the original), so making the `Content` immutable is a bit too harsh (unless I'm misunderstanding what that implies).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `unique_ptr` is not copyable or copy-assignable, so if you want another, you need to call a constructor. (Of course there are ways around but you need to be explicit about doing the nasty stuff.)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of common strategies here:

#### Privacy with defensive copying

In this strategy, you'd have the owner have a *private* reference to the content, and if it's appropriate for it to give out copies of that content, to do so via a defensive copy:

```
class Owner {
    private Content content;

    // ...unnecessary detail omitted...

    public Content getContent() {
        return new Content(this.content);
    }
}
```

The [`Cloneable` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) can sometimes be useful here.

#### Immutable objects

The other common strategy is to use *immutable objects* (e.g., ensure that `Content`, once instantiated, cannot be modified). Then you don't care who has a reference to the content, since they cannot change it.

Comment: Upvoted. This is sensible, but you can still hack round the private reference using *reflection*. The only *sensible* option, I think, is immutability.

Comment: Well with `Content a = owner.getContent(); Content b = a;` you still copy the reference, don't you?

Comment: @abbath: You copy the reference to the *copy* of the content, not the content that the owner has a private copy of. If the owner of that copy *also* wants to keep it private, they'd do the same thing as above.

Comment: Ah, I see. But then you can neither reach the original object anywhere else than inside the Owner, right?

Comment: @abbath: That's the idea, as I understand the question.

Comment: @Bathsheba I wouldn't count modifying through reflection as a problem; if someone wants to be nasty they will always find a way (if nothing else, then going native and bit-modifying anything they want in C). They just need to be explicit about doing so and that's easy to locate. The question was about preventing unintentional misuses.

Comment: @Bathsheba: :-) Of course, you can get around immutability via reflection as well... But absolutely, immutables have a lot going for them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Indeed you can (which somewhat weakens my argument ;-) ). See the Java answer to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28786/write-a-program-that-makes-2-2-5

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't.

Once you have established a reference to an object, there's absolutely nothing you can do to stop someone form assigning another reference to that object via that established reference.

Java programmers get round this by making objects *immutable* (see `java.lang.String`). Then you ought not give two hoots about who else is referring to a particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the class Content as Immutable by doing this:

1. Don't provide "setter" methods — methods that modify fields or objects referred to by fields.
2. Make all fields final and private.
3. Don't allow subclasses to override methods. The simplest way to do this is to declare the class as final.
4. If the instance fields include references to mutable objects, don't allow those objects to be changed

Here is a java official doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have something like that. There are some language elements that can *help* with such requirements:

1. Enums that have only one constant; to be used as "built-in" singletons
2. Methods in Collections to create **immutable** copies of collections
3. And of course, you can make all fields in your class final; so they get initialized only during construction time; to prevent later changes

But as Java is also missing a *const* concept, you can partially work around such things. Like in:

```
class Foo {
  private final List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();
```

doesn't mean that instances of Foo will be **immutable** - as you still can add/remove elements to that list owned by Foo.

Similar; given

```
List<Foo> root = ...
List<Foo> immutableCopy = Collections.unmodifiableList(root);
```

one can still **change** that *immutableCopy* ... by messing up *root*.